# Is it possible to create a calendar widget in databricks?

Tags: widget, databricks

I just wanted to use a date as an input for a notebook and wanted to manage the parameter handling with widgets. The standard documentation for databricks widgets (https://docs.databricks.com/user-guide/notebooks/widgets.html) does not provide information about calendar widgets or the possibility to create a new widget type.

They only provide

- text
- multiselect
- combobox
- drop-down

Now I create different drop-down widgets for day, month and year, but this is not a good solution in my opinion.

Did anyone make any experience with widget creation/ modification in databricks?

Comment: You cannot create your own widget types in databricks unfortunatly. Is just entering the date as a string in a text widget not an option?

Answer (score 0):

### Databricks widget API

While you cannot create custom widgets you can use the **text** widget to pass a standard date format like `yyyy-mm-dd` then convert to datetime/timestamp.

```py
import pandas as pd 

# create the date widget
dbutils.widgets.text(name="date", defaultValue="2022-01-01")

# get the value of date widget
date = dbutils.widgets.get("date")

# convert to timestamp with a forced format
pd.to_datetime(date, format="%Y-%m-%d")
```

### ipywidgets

If you do not need to parameterize the notebook you can use **ipywidgets** within Databricks (currently in public preview as of Aug 2022). Requires Databricks Runtime 11.0 or above.

```py
import ipywidgets as widgets

# create widget
date_widget = widgets.DatePicker(
    description='Pick a Date',
    disabled=False
)

# display widget
date_widget

# get widget value
date_widget.value
```